# How to unblock unsafe port on Chromebook?

Tags: networking, chromebook

I am unable to access port 6666 on my Chromebook. The tutorials online say to edit the startup command, but I can't on my Chromebook. Is there another way to do this? A hidden URL, like “net-internals”, but different?

Comment: You should be able to do this from the bash shell in developer mode.  If you haven't got developer mode activated, then first-time activation will powerwash the chromebook.